# Next line array if a condition is achieved

Tags: perl

I have a text in a file F1 each sentence in line, and another file contain the part of speech(POS) of each word in the text for example:

F1 contains:

```
he lives in paris\n
he jokes
```

F2 contains:

```
he pro\n
lives verb\n
in prep\n
paris adv_pl\n
he pro\n
jokes verb\n
```

I would like to parse each sentence of F1 and extract the POS of each word. I arrived to extract the POS of the first sentence, but the program can't parse the second line. This is the code:

```
open( FILE,    $filename )       || die "Problème d'ouverture du ficher en entrée";
open( FILEOUT, ">$filenameout" ) || die "Problème d'ouverture";

open( F,  "/home/ahmed/Bureau/test/corpus.txt" ) || die " Pb pour ouvrir";
open( F2, "/home/ahmed/Bureau/test/corp.txt" )   || die " Pb pour ouvrir";
my $z;
my $y = 0;
my $l;
my $li;
my $pos;

while ( $ligne = <F> ) {

    while ( $li = <F2> ) {    # F2 POS
        chomp($li);
        # prem contain the first word of F2 in each line, 
        # deux contain the POS of this word
        ( $prem, $deux ) = ( $li =~ m/^\W*(\w+)\W+(\w+)/ );
        print "premier: $prem\n";

        chomp($ligne);
        @val = split( / /, $ligne );   # corpus de texte
        $l = @val;

        while ( $y < $l ) {  # $l length of sentence
            $z = $val[$y];
            print "z : $z\n";

            if ( $z eq $prem ) {
                print "true\n";
                $pos .= "POSw" . $y . "=" . $deux . " ";
                ++$y;
            } else {
                last;
            }
        }
    }
    print FILEOUT "$pos\n";
    $pos = "";
}
```

The result I had in the terminal:

```
premier: he
z : he
true

premier : lives
z : lives
true

premier : in
z : in
true

premier : paris
z : paris
true
premier : he
premier : jokes
```

The first sentence has 4 words, when it pass 4, we must go to the next line in the text, I can't arrive to solve it.

Comment: You need to reset `$y` to zero, like: `} else { $y = 0; last; }`.

Comment: Also, no need to chomp if you extract by capture groups or split on `' '`, not `/ /`.

Comment: I just wanted to start helping you but got stuck when I realized that **you don't actually tell what your desired output is.** Please [edit] your question and tell us. Also, what is `POS`? Usually the term is used for _position_ but in your case it seems to be grammatical type of a word as fetched from F2.

Comment: Does `adv_pl` mean "adverb plural"? *Paris* is a proper noun, and adverbs can't be plural!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your script.

- You ***must always*** `use strict; use warnings;` to show the most common syntax and/or typing errors, unused variables, etc.
- You should always use the three-parameter `open` and no global FILEHANDLEs (see [opentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)).
- You should use some sensible names for your filehandles, not FH, FH1, etc. but `$fh_sentences` and `$fh_grammar` (or other meaningful names).

So far for the general part. Now let's get more specific:

- Your outer loop (`F`) reads the sentences one by one. The next loop (`F2`) reads the grammatical types but it does so only once for the first sentence. When the F2 file is read, subsequent calls to `<F2>` will always return `undef` because the file was already read. You have to reset the filepointer to the beginning of the file after each sentence or -- even better -- read the file F2 in advance and store its contents in a hash.
- Iterating over an array of words in a sentence is easier with `foreach my $word (@words)`. No need to do the housekeeping of index variables (like `$y`) yourself.
- `chomp`ing and `split`ting the sentences should be moved outside the F2 loop because `$ligne` doesn't change in the loop and only burns CPU cycles.

Putting this together I end up with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Read the grammar file, F2, into a hash:
my %grammar;
open( my $fh_grammar, '<', 'F2' ) or die "Pb pour ouvrir F2: $!\n";
while( my $ligne = <$fh_grammar> ) {
    my ($prem, $deux) = ( $ligne =~ m/^\W*(\w+)\W+(\w+)/ );
    $grammar{$prem} = $deux;
}
close($fh_grammar);

# The hash is now:
#   %grammar = (
#       'he'    => 'pro',
#       'lives  => 'verb',
#       'in'    => 'prep',
#       'paris' => 'adv_pl'
#       'jokes' => 'verb'
#   );

# Read the sentences from F1 and check the grammar:
open( my $fh_sentences, '<', 'F1' ) or die "Pb pour ouvrir F1: $!\n";
while( my $ligne = <$fh_sentences> ) {
    my @words = split(/\s+/, $ligne );
    foreach my $word (@words) {
        print "z:    $word\n";
        if ( exists $grammar{$word} ) {
            print "true; $grammar{$word}\n";
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
close($fh_sentences);
```

Output:

```
z:    he
true; pro
z:    lives
true; verb
z:    in
true; prep
z:    paris
true; adv_pl

z:    he
true; pro
z:    jokes
true; verb
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve the above problem in different way like :

First read the POS file and put it in hash

Code :

```
my $filename = "F2";
open FH2, $filename or die "Error";
my %POS_hash;
while(<FH2>)
{
    chomp($_);
    my @arr = split(/ /, $_); # you can change the split function
    $POS_hash{$arr[0]} = $arr[1];
}
```

Now read your file and replace it with the POS

```
my $filename1 = "F1";
open FH1, $filename1 or die "Error";
while(<FH1>)
{
   chomp($_);
   my @arr = split(/ /, $_); # you can change the split function
  foreach my $val (@arr)
  {
     if(exists $POS_hash{$val})
     {
        print "$POS_hash{$val}\t";
     }
  }
  print "\n";

}
```

I believe this is a better way for your problem. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This gives `Use of my $_ is experimental at so27.pl line 15. syntax error at so27.pl line 8, near "$POS_hash{" so27.pl had compilation errors.`. Your FH2 is never opened and in `my $POS_hash{$arr[0]} = $arr[1];` the `my` is wrong.

Comment: I made a mistake and corrected it. Please check it. now

Comment: `Name "main::filename1" used only once`, `Name "main::filename" used only once`, `Name "main::FH1" used only once`, `Name "main::FH2" used only once`, `Use of uninitialized value $filename in open`. Please test your code before publishing it. This doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: Thanks Borodin for helping me to recognize errors in the code

Comment: Great, thanks, it works, in your opinion, it's better to use hash than arrays or list ? or in wich situation we use hash or arrays?

Comment: When you have some key value kind of problem then use of hash is much good.